# Is there any method to pass an Image as a Variable from php to python Script

Tags: php, python, exec

I m getting an error while passing base64 encoded image String to python Script ....that unable to run shell_execute("python hello.py $data")
Here is my code

**php File**

```
 <?php
 echo "Good Work";
 $img = file_get_contents("aaaa.jpg");
 $data = base64_encode($img);
 $output = shell_exec("python hello.py".$data);
 echo $output;
 ?>
```

**hello.py File**

```
import sys
import base64
image_64_encode=sys.argv[1]
with open("image.jpg","wb") as fh:
     fh.write(base64.decodebytes(image_64_encode))`
```

Comment: You're going to need a space for your argument .. `$output = shell_exec("python hello.py".$data);`  Needs to look like  `$output = shell_exec("python hello.py " . $data);`  **otherwise** if `data='foo';` it would look like `shell_exec("python hello.pyfoo");`

Comment: Also .. is `shell_exec` enabled in your `php` configuration?  Most installs it comes "black listed" and it needs to be enabled in the `.ini`

Comment: Zak sir it doesnt work

Comment: sir when i am passing the simple string for example $str="sohaib" instead of $data then it works but in case of image it doesnt work i dont know why

Comment: Does you Base64 contain things that would mess with the `arg`  For example `$` or `"` or `'` etc etc etc ..

Comment: Zak sir yes i have tried with both cases another string work and displayed but encoded string doesnt work

Comment: Yes my encoded string contains things something like this / \ etc

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to write your base64 to a separated file so that no encoding is needed ..  I have slightly altered your code to reflect this.

**PHP FILE**

```
<?php
$img = file_get_contents("image.jpg");
$data = base64_encode($img);
$content = $data;
$file = "myFile.base64";
$fp = fopen($file,"wb");
fwrite($fp,$content);
fclose($fp);

$output = shell_exec("python hello.py $file");
echo $output;
?>
```

**PYTHON FILE**

```
import sys
import base64
file=sys.argv[1]
f = open(file)
base_64 = f.read()

# print (base_64)
# Do what you want with the base_64 variable.

image_64_encode=base_64
with open("image.jpg","wb") as fh:
   fh.write(base64.decodebytes(image_64_encode))
```